# How to enable guest account to copy files to system in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, guest-account

There is a guest account in my system. Since it is a guest account I cannot copy files to my system. Is there any way to copy files to the system (to partitions in Hard disk) from guest account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself.

1. Open **Local Users and Groups**.
2. Double click **Groups** and read the description of all groups.
3. Now double click on **Users**.
4. Right click on the Guest account, select **Properties**.
5. Under **Member of** Tab Click **Add**.
6. Click **Advanced** > **Add** > **Find now**.
7. Now from the list appeared select the appropriate group. Click Ok.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the guest account to an Administrator should fix this problem.
The following is from [WikiHow.com](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-a-Guest-Account-to-an-Administrator-in-Windows)

1. **Access "User Accounts.**" You can find the "User Accounts" window via "Control Panel." To open "Control Panel," press Win+X and select it from the menu that appears.

Note: You must be signed in as an Administrator in order to make changes to user accounts. You may be prompted for your administrative password before making changes, so be sure to have this on hand.
    - Changing a Guest account into an Administrator presupposes that Guest accounts have been enabled on your computer. To toggle Guest accounts on or off, select "Manager another account" (instructions below) and then select the Guest account. Dialogue will appear asking you if you wish to turn the Guest account on or off, allowing you to select your preference. Note that the Guest account is turned off by default.

2. **Select "Manage another account.**" You'll see this located under the two options to "Change your account name" and "Change your account type." To access "Manage another account" directly from your desktop, you may also simply press
3. **Choose the account you wish to adjust.** You'll see each of your active user accounts appear along with avatars and account descriptions. Just click on the Guest account for which to want to allow administrative privileges.
4. **Change the account type.** After selecting the desired user account, you'll see a menu of options appear. Begin by selecting "Change the account type." Then place a dot in the circle next to "Administrator" (the other option being a "Standard" user account). Simply close the "User Accounts" window when finished, and your change will take effect.

Comment: I don't want it to make an Administrator account.

Comment: It's inherently not safe to give guest users access to personal (or company) files. If you somewhat trust the users, then give them more privileges. Otherwise, maybe copy relevant files directly to the users user folder?